# Append text by matching object array's attribute and element id's digit

Tags: javascript

I have a list of object array with id and value as its properties. Basically what I want is, the `num.items[i].value` should go in each div as pair. `One: one` and so on. 
If `num.items[i].id` doesn't have the digit (like the array doesn't include id 3) then the `id="digit_3"` should be left blank.

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>One: <div id="digit_1">s</div></li>
  <li>Two: <div id="digit_2">sd</div></li>
  <li>Three: <div id="digit_3">sdf</div></li>
  <li>Four: <div id="digit_4">sdf</div></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
var num = { 
    items:  [
        { id:4,  value:"four"},
        { id:1,  value:"one"},
        { id:2,  value:"two"},
    ]

};
for(var i=0; i<num.items.length; i++){
        document.getElementById("digit_"+i+1).innerHTML = i+1;
        console.log(i+1)
}
```

Required output

```
One: one
Two: two
Three: 
Four: four
```

I know we cannot compare the id digit but any modification in HTML is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's really simple - you just have to understand arrays and objects:

```js
var num = {
    items: [{
            id: 4,
            value: "four"
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            value: "one"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            value: "two"
        },
    ]

};
var cleanableElements = document.querySelectorAll("ul li div");
for (var i = 0; i < cleanableElements.length; i++) {
 cleanableElements[i].innerHTML = '';
}

var index;
for (var i = 0; i < num.items.length; i++) {
 index = num.items[i].id;
    document.getElementById("digit_" + index).innerHTML = num.items[i].value;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>One:
        <div id="digit_1"></div>
    </li>
    <li>Two:
        <div id="digit_2"></div>
    </li>
    <li>Three:
        <div id="digit_3"></div>
    </li>
    <li>Four:
        <div id="digit_4"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Best idea would be to select all elements with querySelectorAll and setting empty before next step. You can't really detect all #digit_X id's so you can't just check for unchanged DIVs as you can't reliably detect them all.

Answer (score 1):

You should loop `ul li div` then check id whether is in `num.items`.
Assuming your id format is `digit_*`.

```js
var num = { 
    items:  [
        { id:4,  value:"four"},
        { id:1,  value:"one"},
        { id:2,  value:"two"},
    ]

}



function checkItems(num){
  items = document.querySelectorAll('#target_div li div')
  indexes = num.items.reduce( (pre, cur) => {
    pre[cur.id] = cur.value
    return pre
  }, {}) // loop num.items then create one dict with key=id.
  
  items.forEach(function(item){ //loop ul li div, then check whether id in dict=indexes.
    let ids = item.id.split('_')
    if(ids[1] in indexes){
      item.innerHTML += ' @Found:'+item.id
    } else {
      item.innerHTML = ''
    }
  })
}
checkItems(num)
```

```html
<ul id="target_div">
  <li>One: <div id="digit_1">s</div></li>
  <li>Two: <div id="digit_2">sd</div></li>
  <li>Three: <div id="digit_3">sdf</div></li>
  <li>Four: <div id="digit_4">sdf</div></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know I did something awkward but if div have already some value then above example will not work expect @sphinx answer I guess

```js
var num = {
    items: [{
            id: 4,
            value: "four"
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            value: "one"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            value: "two"
        },
    ]

};

var idsArray = [];
var valuesArray = [];
for (var value of num.items) {
    idsArray.push(value.id);
    valuesArray.push(value.value);
}

var maxId = Math.max(...idsArray);


for (var i = 1; i <= maxId; i++) {
    if (idsArray.indexOf(i) !== -1) {

        document.getElementById("digit_" + i).innerHTML = valuesArray[idsArray.indexOf(i)];
    } else {

        document.getElementById("digit_" + i).innerHTML = "";
    }

}
```

```css
div {
  display: inline
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One: <div id="digit_1">s</div></li>
  <li>Two: <div id="digit_2">sd</div></li>
  <li>Three: <div id="digit_3">sdf</div></li>
  <li>Four: <div id="digit_4">sdf</div></li>
</ul>
```